# Getting Android contacts information

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a contacts name from my contacts by using an Intent, it seems the method I found earlier is deprecated and when I try to use it my app force quits. I'm new to Android development and any help would be appreciated.

```
public void openContacts(View view) {
    Intent contactsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactsIntent, 1);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts.People.NAME));
            TextView contactName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contact_name_textview);
            contactName.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm calling the openContacts function as an onClick event for a button. Once I've picked my contact I would like to set the name to a TextView that I have already made.

Comment: Provide stacktrace please